# Trying to reverse a C-string but it is not working

Tags: c, for-loop, reverse, c-strings, function-definition

I am trying to reverse this C-string and I thought I did it correct but the string remains the same when it passes through the function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* reverse(char* string); 

int main(int arc, char* argv[]) {
    char word[] = "Hello World!";

    printf("%s\n", word);
    printf("%s\n", reverse(word));
    return 0;
}

char* reverse(char* string) {
    int i, j, n = 0;int len = 0;char temp;

//Gets string length
    for (i = 0; *(string + i) != '0'; i++) {
        len++;
    }

//Reverses string
    for (j = len - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        temp = string[n];
        string[n] = string[j];
        string[j] = temp;
        n++; 
    }

    return &string[0];
}
```

Expected output:
Hello World!
!dlroW olleH

Comment: Running full length and swapping will swap each pair twice.

Comment: `*(string + i) != '0'` continues the loop until it finds a “0” character, not until it finds a null character.

Comment: You need to stop when `j` reaches the center of the string, i.e. divide `len` by 2.  Otherwise you'll keep going, undoing all of the swaps you did.

Comment: This is the most common error in questions about reversing strings. Everyone seems to get this wrong.

Comment: The best way to get the string length is to call `strlen()` — you may be working under rules that say "no functions from `<string.h>`", but it would be better to say so if that's the case.

Comment: Not using pointers, I like code like this: `char *reverse(char *string) { int i = 0; int j = strlen(string); while (i < --j) { char c = string[i]; string[i++] = string[j]; string[j] = c; } return string; }` — where you can replace the call to `strlen()` with a loop if your rules of engagement say "no `strlen()`".

Comment: @Barmar "Everyone seems to get this wrong." --> Those who get it right likely are not posting. More like those who did not get it, get it wrong for this same wrong reason.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Good point. I should stop wondering why about "obvious" mistakes, since it's selection bias here.

Answer (score 2):

For starters there is a typo

```
for (i = 0; *(string + i) != '0'; i++) {
```

You have to write

```
for (i = 0; *(string + i) != '\0'; i++) {
```

That is instead of the character `'0'` you have to use `'\0'` or `0`.

In this for loop

```
for (j = len - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    temp = string[n];
    string[n] = string[j];
    string[j] = temp;
    n++; 
}
```

the string is reversed twice.:) As a result you get the same string.

The function can look for example the following way

```
char * reverse(char *string) 
{
    //Gets string length
    size_t n = 0;

    while ( string[n] != '\0' ) ++n;

    //Reverses string
    for ( size_t i = 0, m = n / 2; i < m; i++ )
    {
        char temp = string[i];
        string[i] = string[n - i - 1];
        string[n - i - 1] = temp;
    }

    return string;
}
```

Or the function can be defined the following way using pointers

```
char * reverse(char *string) 
{
    //Gets string length
    char *right = string;

    while ( *right ) ++right;

    //Reverses string
    if ( right != string )
    {
        for ( char *left = string; left < --right; ++left )
        {
            char temp = *left;
            *left = *right;
            *right = temp;
        }
    }

    return string;
}
```

The same approach of the function implementation without using pointers can look the following way

```
char * reverse(char *string) 
{
    //Gets string length
    size_t n = 0;    
    while ( string[n] != '\0' ) ++n;

    //Reverses string
    if ( n != 0 )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < --n; ++i )
        {
            char temp = string[i];
            string[i] = string[n];
            string[n] = temp;
        }
    }

    return string;
}
```

Here is one more solution. I like it most of all. Tough it is inefficient but it is not trivial as the early presented solutions. It is based on an attempt of one beginner to write a function that reverses a string.:)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *reverse( char *string )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    while (string[n]) ++n;

    while (!( n < 2 ))
    {
        char c = string[0];
        memmove( string, string + 1, --n );
        string[n] = c;
    }

    return string;
}

int main( void )
{
    char string[] = "Hello World!";

    puts( string );
    puts( reverse( string ) );
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello World!
!dlroW olleH
```

Of course instead of manually calculating the length of a string in all the presented solutions there could be used standard string function `strlen` declared in the header `<string.h>`.

Comment: Don't include a loop-invariant divide in the loop exit test.  At best it's relying on the optimizer moving it out for you.  Better to compute the value *outside* of the loop.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the input `word[]` is an array, which decays to a pointer when passed to the reverse function.

In the for loop, instead of using `n` to keep track of the position, I suggest you to use `i` and `j` to keep track of the start and end of the string, and increment and decrement them respectively and use `strlen` to get the length of string.

Also, as it is mentionned above by **@Vlad from Moscow**, in your `for` loop you are checking for `0` but it should be `\0` which is the null character.

Please find down below an update of your posted code that is generating the expected result :

```
#include <stdio.h>    

char* reverse(char* string); 

int main(int arc, char* argv[]) {
    char word[] = "Hello World!";

    printf("%s ", word);
    printf("%s\n", reverse(word));
    return 0;
}

char* reverse(char* string) {
    int i, j;
    char temp;
    int len = strlen(string);

    //Reverses string
    for (i = 0, j = len - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
        temp = string[i];
        string[i] = string[j];
        string[j] = temp;
    }
    return &string[0];
}
```

The output is as expected: **Hello World! !dlroW olleH**

*Aditionnally, you can include the header <string.h> or explicitly
provide a declaration for 'strlen' to avoid the warning that indicate to implicitly declaring library function 'strlen' with type 'unsigned long (const char* **)' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]*