# Program to reverse string truncates result

Tags: c, char, reverse, c-strings, swap

I am a noob programmer. I have written this program in C that is to take in a string input and then reverse it.  However when it prints the result, it gives some garbage values and a truncated version of the string itself. I have no idea what's wrong any clue?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    char s[50] = "";

    int start;
    int tmp = 0;
    int len;
    int i;
    int end;

    printf("Enter String: ");

    fgets(s, 99, stdin);

    len = strlen(s);
    printf("String Length is: %i\n", len);

    end = len - 1;

    for (start = 0; start <= end; start++)
    {
            tmp = s[end];
            s[end] = s[start];
            s[start] = s[tmp];
            end--;
    }
    printf("Reversed String Is: ");

    for (i = 0; i <= len; i++)
            putchar(s[i]);
```

}

for example: the string "a man my son" returns " nam a".

i tried changing the increment values to no avail.

i also added a printf statement that prints the string length, which shows the correct value.

Comment: You have a typo, use: s[start] = tmp (the way it's current written you are indexing into array s using tmp when you just want to assign tmp)

Comment: So you have allocated a string of 50 characters, but giving `fgets` a green light to read 99 into it...

Answer (score 4):

As it was already pointed out in comments you have two typos. The first one is that the character array `s` is declared with `50` elements

```
char s[50] = "";
```

but in the call of `fgets`

```
fgets(s, 99, stdin);
```

there are specified the value `99` instead of `50`.

The second one is that in this statement

```
        s[start] = s[tmp];
```

the right operand of the assignment is incorrect. Instead you have to write

```
        s[start] = tmp;
```

There are also other problems. For example the function `fgets` can append the input string with the new line character `'\n'` that you should remove from the string before reversing it.

Also in general you should use type `size_t` instead of the type `int` for string lengths. It is the return type of the function `strlen`.

The program can look the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    char s[50] = "";

    printf( "Enter String: " );

    fgets( s, sizeof( s ), stdin );

    size_t n = strcspn( s, "\n" );

    s[n] = '\0';

    printf( "String Length Is: %zu\n", n );

    if ( n != 0 )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < --n; i++ )
        {
            char c = s[i];
            s[i] = s[n];
            s[n] = c;
        }
    }

    printf( "Reversed String Is: \"%s\"\n", s );
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter String: a man my son
String Length Is: 12
Reversed String Is: "nos ym nam a"
```

If you do not want to change the variable `n` that keeps the length of the string then the for loop can look the following way

```
    if ( n != 0 )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0, j = n; i < --j; i++ )
        {
            char c = s[i];
            s[i] = s[j];
            s[j] = c;
        }
    }
```

Pay attention to that you should always declare variables in minimum scopes where they are used.

Also I advice you to see my answer to the following question. I hope it will be useful for you.
[Trying to reverse a C-string but it is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75189843/trying-to-reverse-a-c-string-but-it-is-not-working/75189905#75189905)

Answer (score 0):

This will work as you intended. See my // comments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char s[50];

    int start;
    int tmp = 0;
    int len;
    int i;
    int end;

    printf("Enter String: ");

    fgets(s, 99, stdin);

    len = strlen(s);
    printf("String Length is: %i\n", len);

    end = len - 1;

    for (start = 0; start <= end/2; start++)  //go halfway.
    {
            tmp = s[end];
            s[end] = s[start];
            s[start] = tmp;                   //use VALUE not index
            end--;
    }
    printf("Reversed String Is: ");

    for (i = 0; i <= len; i++)
            putchar(s[i]);
    putchar('\n');   //add this to get newline
}
```

Comment: It seems you are overqualified.:)

Comment: It will not work as intended if I input a string over 50 characters long. Unless you intended some undefined behavior.

Comment: So let's make SO a free code-writing service, because we are too lazy to explain what was wrong with OP's code. That being said, your code is incorrect.

Comment: I made MINIMAL corrections to get this to work. Rest is up to the OP to fix.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    
    char s[50] = "";
    char d[50] = "";

    long int start;
    long int len;
    long int end;

    printf("Enter String: ");

    fgets(s, 99, stdin);

    len = strlen(s);
    printf("String Length is: %ld\n", len);

    end = len - 1;

    long int index = end;
    for (start = 0; start <= end; start++)  {
            d[start] = s[index];
            index--;
    }
    printf("Reversed String Is: %s\n", d);
}
```